# Allocation memory error with use struct for c

Tags: c, dynamic-allocation

I wrote a code for managing a library; the compilation is done but during the simulation I obtained an `Allocation error (case2)` and I don't know why. 
The first case works correctly but if I entered more than one name in the first case, the second case doesn't work.

What did I do wrong? I hope I was clear enough.

```
typedef struct {
    char name[80];
    char **books;
    int books_num;
} Subscription;

int main() {
    // Variables declaration:
    int option = 0, subs_num = 0, i = 0, books_num = 0;
    Subscription *subs_library;
    char **books;
    char subs_new_name[80], book_new_name[80];

    printf("Choose an option\n");
    do {
        scanf("%d", &option);
        switch (option) {
          case 1:
            printf("Case 1: enter a new name\n");
            scanf("%s", subs_new_name);
            if (subs_num == 0) {
                subs_library = malloc(sizeof(Subscription));
            } else {
                subs_library = realloc(subs_library, sizeof(Subscription));
            }
            strcpy(subs_library[subs_num].name, subs_new_name);
            subs_library[subs_num].books_num = 0;
            subs_num++;
            printf("ADDED\n");  
            break;

          case 2:
            printf("Case 2: enter the book name\n");
            scanf("%s", book_new_name);

            if (books_num == 0) {
                books = malloc(sizeof(char*));
                books[books_num] = malloc(80 * sizeof(char));
            } else {
                books = realloc(books, sizeof(char*));
                books[books_num] = malloc(80 * sizeof(char));
            }

            if (books[books_num] == NULL) {
                printf("Allocation Error\n");
                exit(1);
            }

            strcpy(books[books_num], book_new_name);
            books_num++;
            printf("ADDED\n"); 
            break;
        }
    } while (option != 7);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you type in 2?  This would give you case 2.  Also, you probably want to prompt the user before reading input.  The `scanf("%d", &option);` reads an `int` from _stdin_.

Comment: A general tip: Don't reassign to the pointer you try to reallocate. What if `realloc` returns `NULL`? Then you loose the original pointer. Also, you don't actually *check* if the allocations go okay.

Comment: As a style suggestion, I suggest using more traditional indentation.

Comment: Your `malloc(sizeof(char *))` only allocates the size of one pointer, not the size of the whole array that you need.

Comment: What you did wrong is code presentation. I reformatted the code for readability, you MUST learn to do this on your own, as you type.  You will avoid many bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code to reallocate the arrays is incorrect.  You do not allocate enough room for the new array sizes.  When you reallocate these arrays, you pass the size of a single element, therefore the array still has a length of 1 instead of `subs_num + 1`.  The size passed to `realloc` should be the number of elements times the size of a single element in bytes.

Initialize `subs_library` and `books` to `NULL` and change your array reallocations:

```
    if (subs_num == 0) {
        subs_library = malloc(sizeof(Subscription));
    } else {
        subs_library = realloc(subs_library, sizeof(Subscription));
    }
```

Into this:

```
    subs_library = realloc(subs_library, (subs_num + 1) * sizeof(*subs_library));
```

And do the same for `books`, change:

```
    if (books_num == 0) {
        books = malloc(sizeof(char*));
        books[books_num] = malloc(80 * sizeof(char));
    } else {
        books = realloc(books, sizeof(char*));
        books[books_num] = malloc(80 * sizeof(char));
    }
```

To this:

```
    books = realloc(books, (books_num + 1) * sizeof(*books));
    books[books_num] = malloc(80 * sizeof(char));
```

Or simpler:

```
    books = realloc(books, (books_num + 1) * sizeof(*books));
    books[books_num] = strdup(book_new_name);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It works. Can you explain me why it didn't work before?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is with `scanf` reading a string only until a separator, in your case - a whitespace separating multiple names entered. The characters after separator remain in the input buffer and get immediately processed by other calls to `scanf`.

You should consider using `getline` for reading name(s) and checking return values from other calls to `scanf`.

Comment: Hi, i tried with getline it didn't work so I don't think it is the problem

Comment: @Juliette: it is not the *only* problem... Hertz is right, reading the name with `scanf("%s", subs_new_name);` will only read a single word and crash if this word is longer than 79 characters.  Use `scanf("%79[^\n]", subs_new_name);`, and the same applies to `book_new_name`.

Comment: I prefer using [`getline()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) and using `NULL` for the first parameter so it allocates enough space for a new string for you.  Just don't forget to `free()` it.  This also removes your 80-character limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Your reallocation `realloc(books, sizeof(char *))` only allocates the size of one pointer `char *`, not the size of the enlarged array that you need:

```
    books=realloc(books,sizeof(char*));
```

You need to multiply the size of a pointer (`char *`) by the number of books you plan on storing in the array.  You maintain the number of books in `books_num`.

As Joachim Pileborg said, with every allocation/reallocation, you want this to be one more than the current size.  For the first allocation (`malloc()`), you want to allocate for one book, which is 1 times `sizeof(char *)`.  This happens to be equivalent to your existing code, which is fine.  But the reallocation (`realloc()`) reallocates for the same size every time (only enough for one pointer), so you're not enlarging the allocation.  You need to multiply the size required for one pointer (`sizeof(char *)`) by the number of pointers you want, which is `books_num + 1`.  As in Joachim's answer, this is

```
    books = realloc(books, (books_num + 1)*sizeof(char *));
```

This will enlarge the allocation of the array `books` by one more pointer.  Then, on the next line you correctly allocate a string of size 80.

Your `subs_library` has the same reallocation issue.

### Less frequent reallocation

You might want to resize an allocation less frequently.  In this situation, you are reallocating every time you add an entry.  One simple technique to reduce the number of reallocations is to double the allocation size every time it gets full.  But you have to maintain the allocation size (capacity) and check for it whenever you add something.  For example:

```
char **buffer;     /* buffer of pointers to char */
int capacity = 1;  /* number of elements allocated for */
int size = 0;      /* number of elements actually used */
```

Then the initial allocation is

```
/* Initial allocation */
buffer = malloc(capacity*sizeof(*buffer));
```

And to add some `char *new_item` to the `buffer`

```
/* When adding an element */
if ( size == capacity ) {
    /* Double allocation every time */
    capacity *= 2;

    /* Reallocate the buffer to new capacity */
    realloc(buffer, capacity*sizeof(*buffer));
}

/* Item will fit, add to buffer */
buffer[size++] = new_item;
```

Notice that I have used `sizeof(*buffer)` instead of `sizeof(char *)`.  This makes the compiler figure out what the type and size is.  That way, if I change the type of `buffer` for some reason, I don't have to change more places in the code.  Another thing that I left out for brevity is that you should always check the return values to make sure they are not `NULL`.

Comment: sorry I didn't understand your answer, it is what I did, isn't?

Comment: @e0k: while your answer is correct and well documented, it seems well beyond the current skill level of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your reallocation calls. For example you do

```
realloc(books,sizeof(char*))
```

This reallocates the memory pointed to be `books` to be *one* pointer to character in size, which is exactly what you already have. This will lead you to index *out of bounds* of the allocated memory, something which is *undefined behavior*.

If you want to allocate more than *one* element you need to multiply the base type size with the number of elements you want to allocate, e.g.

```
realloc(books, (books_num + 1) * sizeof(char *))
```

Comment: Hi, I don't think it is the problem or at least it is not the problem in the present case. The "allocation error" appears at the first time I tried to type a new book name, the error is when I used malloc                               if (books_num==0) {books=malloc(sizeof(char*));
                           books[books_num]=malloc(80*sizeof(char));   } anyway I fixed the rest of the code according to your answer thanks