# File IO for unknown number of strings in C

Tags: c, string, file-io, malloc

I have a little experience with C++, and for file IO I would use getline and vectors to append new lines. I need to figure out how to read in a list of 32-bit numbers as strings in C now though, but I don't know how many lines there are ahead of time. This is how I'm used to doing it:

```
vector<string> getFileData()
{// Open file, read in, close, return string vector to main
    ifstream myfile;
    string line;
    vector<string> iflines;

    myfile.open("samplefile.txt");
    while (getline(myfile, line))
        iflines.push_back(line);
    myfile.close();
    return iflines;
}
```

I've read that I need to use malloc and realloc, but I know very little about computer architecture, so if someone could explain to me the general principle or concept that goes into this I'd really appreciate it. I'm having a hard time understanding how these will be able to give me a variable that contains a list of strings that I can return to main without having to preallocate anything. Also what type of variable should I use to store a list of strings in C, a 2-D char array or something else?

Comment: You've tagged this [tag:c], but your code is C++. If you were writing C, you would actually have to reallocate memory yourself. If you're actually using C++, then your code is fine--`vector` handles the reallocation automatically.

Comment: That's what I was trying to say, this is how I would do it in C++, but I need to do this exact same thing in C instead and I don't understand the manual memory allocation. I mean I get that you can allocate memory manually, but the unknown length part is what's tripping me up. Using vectors in C++ I was able to get by with my limited knowledge of hardware, but now I'm a bit stuck.

Comment: Two possibilities: one would be to pre-inspect the file to find the number of lines and length of each, then allocate according. The other (generally more reasonable) one would be about like `vector` does: allocate some space, and when/if you run out, allocate more and copy the data from the old allocation to the new one.

Comment: Once I'm done allocating memory, filling it up, reallocating, etc., how do I figure out how much space I used, where it starts and ends, and have the entire list of strings formatted so I can index each line individually, all contained in one variable to send back to main? I can't seem to wrap my head around the full picture. In C++ it was only a few lines, but it seems far more complicated without vectors.

Comment: Typically you'll start with a `char **lines;` That'll be a dynamically allocated array of strings. From there you have two choices. You can allocate one big block to hold the whole file, and break it into strings by overwriting each `\n` with a `\0`, and putting the address of the beginning of the line into the next spot in `lines`. Secondly, you can read a line at a time into a (large) fixed buffer, allocate as much space as needed for that line, copy data, then store the pointer to the next spot on `lines`.

Comment: Hmm.. but don't I need to specify the size of `char **lines` before I actually know what it needs to be? I don't see how I can just keep adding more lines to it after it's declared.

Comment: @austin Have a read of the [`realloc` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc). That's the typical way to change the size of a dynamically allocated buffer.

Comment: I tried to explain [this common buffer allocation technique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34970237/allocation-memory-error-with-use-struct-for-c/34970316#answer-34970316) to someone the other day.  (See the second half of the answer.)  When the buffer is full, you just double the allocation and keep going.

Comment: Ok thanks for all the help and suggestions. I'm surprised I've been so unsuccessful at just googling a fuction that puts all these concepts together since this seems like something people would need to do fairly often. I guess I have a lot of reading up to do.

Comment: The thing that brings all these concepts together and makes them easy to use is called C++.

Comment: Note that POSIX has a [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) which deals with inputs rather like the C++ `getline()` does (but the interface is, of course, somewhat different). You'll simply need to (a) make sure you allocate an array of pointers, growing it as necessary (but not by one pointer at a time; double the size each time you allocate more space), and (b) making sure that `getline()` allocates a new buffer each time it's used. Alternatively, you can use `strdup()` to duplicate the string, letting `getline()` reuse the space it allocates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way to approach what you are trying to do in C is to do, reading an unknown number of lines (of unknown length), into a *quote* 'array' of lines is to allocate some reasonably anticipated number of pointers (with `malloc` or `calloc`), read/allocate storage for each line, assign the line to an empty pointer and repeat until you reach the limit of pointers. When you reach your original pointer limit, simply `realloc` the number of pointers you have to 2X current and keep going.

You can then parse the line as required. In your case converting each line into a 32-bit value. To read each line, the standard tools for *line-oriented* input in C are `fgets` and `getline`. Since you mentioned `getline` from C++, the unrelated C function use is shown below. `getline` will allocate sufficient space to hold each line of data read. However, it reuses its own buffer, so you need to allocate storage for each line and copy the line returned by `getline`. (`strdup` can do both in a single call).

Look over the following and let me know if you have questions. *Note:* the `enum` is simply used to define a constant for the initial number of pointers allocated. You could do the same with `#define MAXL 64`. Also note that the line index 'idx' is passed as a pointer to the `readfile` function so that the number of lines read is available back in `main` when `readfile` returns:

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <string.h>

enum { MAXL = 64 };

char **readfile (FILE *fp, size_t *idx);
void *xcalloc (size_t n, size_t s);
void *xrealloc_dp (void *ptr, size_t *n);
FILE *xfopen (const char *fn, const char *mode);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char **iflines = NULL;
    size_t i, idx = 0;
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? xfopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    /* read file into dynamically allocated 'iflines' */
    if (!(iflines = readfile (fp, &idx))) return 1;

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file  */

    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++)       /* print lines */
        printf (" line[%2zu] : %s\n", i, iflines[i]);

    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++)   /* free allocated memory */
        free (iflines[i]);
    free (iflines);

    return 0;
}

/* return allocated pointer to array of pointers containing
 * lines from 'fp'
 */
char **readfile (FILE *fp, size_t *idx)
{
    if (!fp) return NULL;

    char **filebuf = NULL;
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t maxl = MAXL, n = 0;
    ssize_t nchr = 0;

    /* allocate MAXL pointers */
    filebuf = xcalloc (MAXL, sizeof *filebuf);

    while ((nchr = getline (&line, &n, fp)) != -1)
    {   /* trim trailing newline or carriage return */
        while (nchr && (line[nchr-1] == '\n' || line[nchr-1] == '\r'))
            line[--nchr] = 0;

        filebuf[(*idx)++] = strdup (line); /* allocate & copy */

        /* realloc as required */
        if (*idx == maxl) filebuf = xrealloc_dp (filebuf, &maxl);
    }
    free (line);  /* free getline allocated memory */

    return filebuf;
}

void *xcalloc (size_t n, size_t s)
{
    register void *memptr = calloc (n, s);
    if (memptr == 0) {
        fprintf (stderr, "xcalloc() error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return memptr;
}

void *xrealloc_dp (void *ptr, size_t *n)
{
    void **p = ptr;
    void *tmp = realloc (p, 2 * *n * sizeof tmp);
    if (!tmp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "xrealloc_dp() error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    p = tmp;
    memset (p + *n, 0, *n * sizeof tmp); /* set new pointers NULL */
    *n *= 2;

    return p;
}

FILE *xfopen (const char *fn, const char *mode)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen (fn, mode);

    if (!fp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "xfopen() error: file open failed '%s'.\n", fn);
        // return NULL;      /* return or exit as desired */
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return fp;
}
```

**Sample Input**

```
$ cat dat/10int_nl.txt
8572
-2213
6434
16330
3034
12346
4855
16985
11250
1495
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/getline_min_fn dat/10int_nl.txt
 line[ 0] : 8572
 line[ 1] : -2213
 line[ 2] : 6434
 line[ 3] : 16330
 line[ 4] : 3034
 line[ 5] : 12346
 line[ 6] : 4855
 line[ 7] : 16985
 line[ 8] : 11250
 line[ 9] : 1495
```

*Note:* `xcalloc`, `xrealloc_dp` and `xfopen` are just helper functions that do appropriate error checking for the respective functions `calloc`, `realloc` and `fopen`. The `xrealloc_dp` name is just indicating that it is reallocating a *pointer-to-pointer-to-type* (commonly called a *double-pointer*). Thus, the `xrealloc_dp` name.

Look it over, and let me know if you have questions, or if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: No problems, glad I could help. Once you see it done, it's not that hard to follow, but putting the pieces together from scratch the first time is a challenge. There a are a number of variations to this approach, but they all follow the same scheme for the most part. Good luck with your coding.

Comment: Yes it all makes sense reading through it, but it would have likely taken me days to piece together on my own. Thanks so much.

Comment: Sure, also note, this approach will read any text file into `iflines`. After you compile it, just make it read it's own source file. You mentioned numbers, if you need the lines converted to 32-bit values, then you would still need to perform the conversion (e.g. `int value = atoi (iflines[x]);` or using `float value = strtof (iflines[x], &ep);`) or using any of the other `strtoX` family of conversions. Let me know if you run into any other issues.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. I think I'll be able to do the manipulations I require as strings, but I will for sure keep those additional suggestions in mind.